# How to create a Java triangle using number like one by one number

Tags: java, for-loop

My code for Java I used

```
System.out.println("* Printing the pattern... *");

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(k + " ");
        k++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output I want is

```
1   
2 6
3 7 10 
4 8 11 13 
5 9 12 14 15
```

Comment: Where does `k` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is unfortunately not correct. Try this simple code where rows is the input parameter:

```
int rows = 5;

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
{
    int number = i;

    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(number + " ");
        number += (rows - j);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

If you look at the wanted result:

```
1   
2 6
3 7 10 
4 8 11 13 
5 9 12 14 15
```

you can see that the first element of the row is going from 1 to the given number of rows. The second element equals to first element + the number of rows - 1. The third element is equals to the second element + the number of rows - 2 and so on.

My code implements this simple algorithm.

Comment: Please read  [How do I ask **and answer** homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: I have modified the answer and added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution (not complete, just to give an idea):

- create a `String` array to contain each row - `rows = new String[n];`
- fill the array with empty strings - `Arrays.fill(rows, "");`
- use a loop for columns - `for (var col = 0; col < n; col++)`
- with a second loop for rows, starting at the actual column number so we get the *triangle* - `for(var row = col; row < n; row++)`
- add the actual number (variable declared outside loops) to the row - `rows[row] += num;`
- increment the number - `num += 1;` (could be done in above statement using `++`, I prefer it explicit)
- after the loops, join all rows separated by newline (or just print it) - `return String.join("\n", rows);`

Alternative: store int in *2d*-array `rows = new int[n][n];`